# Performing a transpose operation on a DirectX Surface Buffer

Tags: directx, video-processing, direct3d, ms-media-foundation

I am using IMFSourceReader with hardware acceleration enabled to decode videos and read them into my application. After the ReadSample call, I get hold of the IDirect3DSurface9 from the IMFSample. At this point, I use the LockRect() call to access the raw-bytes and copy them into my applications buffer.

**I would like to perform additional operations on the GPU such as transpose and a possible conversion of the image data from row-major order to column-major order.**

Is there a Blt operation I can setup to this?

I came across the ID3DXBaseEffect interface but I am not sure that is applicable in my case.

Would appreciate any inputs.

Dinesh

Answer (score 1):

With IDirect3DSurface9, you can use shader (ID3DXBaseEffect).

To do it on GPU directly, before copy the raw-bytes to your application, i will try this :

- Call IMFSourceReader::GetServiceForStream to query for MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE and IDirect3DDeviceManager9.
- use IDirect3DDeviceManager9 to query the IDirect3DDevice9 (IDirect3DDeviceManager9::LockDevice).
- Use IDirect3DDevice9, IDirect3DSurface9, a new RenderTarget, shader, as usual with Directx.
- copy the raw-bytes from the final RenderTarget (after shader apply).

**EDIT**

See here : [mofo7777 github](https://github.com/mofo7777)

Under MediaFoundationTransform > MFTDirectxAware > MFTVideoShaderEffect, i'll show the concept.